# How to use a Reduce() method and converting improper fractions in C# console program

Tags: c#

I’m still new to `C#` programming and I am stuck on the following project. I know it must be easy but I’m brain-locked as to where to place the `Reduce()` method and how to convert the fraction by eliminating the whole number and calling this to the `Reduce()` method. Here is the project:

Add an operator `+()` method that adds two fractions. To add two fractions, first eliminate any whole number part of the value. For example, 2 1/4 becomes 9/4 and 1 3/5 becomes 8/5. Find a common denominator and convert the fractions to it. For example, when adding 9/4 and 8/5, you can convert them to 45/20 and 32/20. Then, you can add the numerators, giving 77/20. Finally, call the `Reduce()` method to reduce the result, restoring any whole number value so the fractional part of the number is less than 1. For example, 77/20 becomes 3 17/20.

Here is the code that I have so far. I’m also going to have an issue with multiplying these fractions and later creating an array but for now I’m trying to take this one step at a time. Any and all responses would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Fraction
{
    public int WholeNumber { get; private set; }
    public int Numerator { get; private set; }
    public int Denominator { get; private set; } 

    private void Reduce()
    {
        if (Numerator < Denominator)
        {
            WholeNumber = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (Numerator == Denominator)
        {
            WholeNumber = 1;
            Numerator = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (Numerator > Denominator)
        {
            WholeNumber = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)Numerator / Denominator);
            Numerator = Numerator - WholeNumber * Denominator;
        }
    } 

    //constructor with three parameters 
    public Fraction(int wholenumber, int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        WholeNumber = wholenumber;
        Numerator = WholeNumber * Denominator + Numerator;
        Reduce();
    }

    //constructor with two parameters 
    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        WholeNumber = 0;
        Numerator = numerator;
        Denominator = denominator;
        Reduce();
    } 

    //parameter less with set values
    public Fraction()
    {
        WholeNumber = 0;
        Numerator = 0;
        Denominator = 1;
    }

    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction firstfraction, Fraction secondfraction)
    {
        if (firstfraction.Denominator == secondfraction.Denominator)
        {
            int firstProduct = (firstfraction.WholeNumber * firstfraction.Denominator) + firstfraction.Numerator;
            int secondProduct = (secondfraction.WholeNumber * secondfraction.Denominator) + secondfraction.Numerator;
            return (new Fraction(firstProduct + secondProduct, firstfraction.Denominator));
        }
        else
        {
            int commondenominator = firstfraction.Denominator * secondfraction.Denominator;
            int firstProduct = ((firstfraction.WholeNumber * firstfraction.Denominator) + firstfraction.Numerator) * secondfraction.Denominator;
            int secondProduct = ((secondfraction.WholeNumber * secondfraction.Denominator) + secondfraction.Numerator) * firstfraction.Denominator;
            return (new Fraction(firstProduct + secondProduct, commondenominator));
        }
    } 


    public Fraction Reduce(int WholeNumber, int Numerator, int Denominator)
    {
        int reduceWhole = (int)WholeNumber;
        while (Numerator > Denominator)
        {
            Numerator -= Denominator;
            reduceWhole += 1;
        }
        while (Denominator % Numerator == 0)
        {
            int factor = (int)Denominator / Numerator;
            Numerator = 1;
            Denominator = factor;
        }

        return new Fraction(reduceWhole, Numerator, Denominator);
    } 

}//end class

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fraction firstfraction = new Fraction();
        Fraction secondfraction = new Fraction();
        Fraction total = firstfraction + secondfraction;
        Console.WriteLine(total);
        Console.Write("Enter whole number portion of fraction: ");
        firstfraction.WholeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter numerator: ");
        firstfraction.Numerator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter denominator: ");
        firstfraction.Denominator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter whole number portion of fraction: ");
        secondfraction.WholeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter numerator: ");
        secondfraction.Numerator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter denominator: ");
        secondfraction.Denominator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("{0} {1}/{2}", firstfraction.WholeNumber, firstfraction.Numerator,
        firstfraction.Denominator);
        Console.WriteLine(" + {0} {1}/{2}", secondfraction.WholeNumber,
        secondfraction.Numerator, secondfraction.Denominator);
        Fraction add = new Fraction();
        add = firstfraction + secondfraction;
        Console.Write("Result of adding two fractions is:{0} {1}/{2}", add.WholeNumber,
        add.Numerator, add.Denominator);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Now I am getting 3 error messages that say the property or indexer

> `'FractionProgram.Fraction.Denominator'` cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible.

Plus do I have the correct calculations for firstProduct and secondProduct?

Comment: You should look into using auto properties to make the first part of the class less verbose.  It also looks like you fractions are immutable and could make the setter portion of your property private.  You should also chain your constructors the other way.  Parameterless constructor calls the one with 2 arguments and passes 0,1 which calls the one with 3 arguments and passes along an extra 0.  That way you only have one set of assignments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to do the problem for you, but I'll give you a few hints that will help you solve the problem by yourself and learn.

First, for the placement of the Reduce method, there are a few ways you can go about it:

- You can have it be an instance method that modifies the values of the Fraction (`myFraction.Reduce()`)
- You can have it be an instance method that doesn't modify the Fraction, but returns a new, reduced fraction (like `string` or your operators) (`myFraction = myFraction.Reduce()`)
- You can turn the above option into a static method (`myFraction = Fraction.Reduce(myFraction)`

From reading the assignment, it looks like you're supposed to use the first one. Do keep in mind that there usually is more than one way to implement a feature like this for your future projects, though.

As for the actual contents of the method, here are a few hints to lead you in the direction of the answer.

- Think about integer division and how it works. Write down a few examples (or test them in code) and see what the answers are.
- Think about the modulus operator. If you haven't learned about it yet, it's an operator that does integer division, but returns the remainder instead of the quotient. If you're not allowed to use that yet, you can replicate it's functionality pretty easily.

The rest of it you should be able to figure out mathematically, but if you still need help just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, so you deserve upvoting. The `Reduce()` method should be part of your fraction class and called in the constructors. You should make your properties  `WholeNumber`, `Numerator`, and `Denominator` readonly to ensure consistency in your fraction:

```
public int WholeNumber { get; private set; }
public int Numerator { get; private set; }
public int Denominator { get; private set; }
```

The method will calculate the `WholeNumber` based on the `Numerator` and `Denominator` as if the whole number is always included in the fraction. It should take care of the situations where the numerator is greater then the denominator, when they are equal, etc. Here is the `Reduce()` method:

```
private void Reduce()
{
    if (Numerator < Denominator)
    {
        WholeNumber = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (Numerator == Denominator)
    {
        WholeNumber = 1;
        Numerator = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (Numerator > Denominator)
    {
        WholeNumber = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)Numerator / Denominator);
        Numerator = Numerator - WholeNumber * Denominator;
    }
}
```

The constructors become:

```
//constructor with three parameters
public Fraction(int wholenumber, int numerator, int denominator)
{
    WholeNumber = wholenumber;
    Numerator = WholeNumber * denominator + numerator;
    Denominator = denominator;

    Reduce();
}

//constructor with two parameters
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    WholeNumber = 0;
    Numerator = numerator;
    Denominator = denominator;
    Reduce();
}
```

Then the operator `+()` becomes:

```
public static Fraction operator+(Fraction firstfraction, Fraction secondfraction)
{
    if (firstfraction.Denominator == secondfraction.Denominator)
    {
        int firstProduct = (firstfraction.WholeNumber * firstfraction.Denominator) + firstfraction.Numerator;
        int secondProduct = (secondfraction.WholeNumber * secondfraction.Denominator) + secondfraction.Numerator;
        return (new Fraction(firstProduct + secondProduct, firstfraction.Denominator));
    }
    else
    {
        int commondenominator = firstfraction.Denominator * secondfraction.Denominator;
        int firstProduct = ((firstfraction.WholeNumber * firstfraction.Denominator) + firstfraction.Numerator) * secondfraction.Denominator;
        int secondProduct = ((secondfraction.WholeNumber * secondfraction.Denominator) + secondfraction.Numerator) * firstfraction.Denominator;
        return (new Fraction(firstProduct + secondProduct, commondenominator));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dradu, I'm still playing around with it and will get back with an update in about half an hour

Comment: Oh I see you have to implement the reduce method in the Fraction class and establish a call in each constructor. Still messing around with it but thanks for the insight.

Comment: Having problems in my Main(string[] args) that is updated above.

Comment: You need to declare separate int values for the numbers, then create the fraction:  `int wholeNumber, numerator, denominator; wholeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); ... firstfraction = new Fraction(wholeNumber, numerator, denominator);` I'm not sure about your `Reduce()` method, I tested with the numbers you provided and it's hanging.